# Filtering json data and reloading the resulted data into myTableView

Tags: objective-c, json, uibutton, nspredicate, xcode4.6

Im trying to load an events(data) (from json file) that matches today's date into my tableView when the today's button is pressed then only the data with today's date will be loaded there and when the future button is pressed the events with later dates will be loaded, the only problem I have here is when i run my program nothing is actually happening when I press in either of these UIbuttons, I got all the events regardless their date and without even clicking on any UIButton, u can see below some of my code, it would be great if someone could figure out what is the problem there and since Im not quiet sure about how to use predicate to filter the data:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *dateEvents;

@end


@implementation HomeViewController {
 NSArray *_events;
 NSArray *_dateEvents;


 }



- (IBAction)upcomingEvents:(id)sender {


NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
NSLog(@"mama"); 

_dateEvents = [_events filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate   predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(Events * event, NSDictionary *bindings){

    return [event.date isEqualToString:dateString];
    }]];
         self.myTableView.dataSource = self;


         [self.myTableView reloadData];
         NSLog(@"yes");

  }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have you verified that `upcomingEvents` is called? Does `_dateEvents` have the correct contents after filtering? Is `_dateEvents` used in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and the other data source methods?

Comment: @MartinR I have one json file which contains all the events with all the dates, upcoming is not called and I don't know if _dateEvents have the correct contents after filtering because all the events are loaded once I start my app regardless I press on today's or future button .. I suspect that this is my problem!! that I didn't call _dateEvents in my data source methods since I don't know how, I just called _events and by the way Im using custom cell in my tableView.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will *definitely* help, because I can't see enough code so be certain that this is your problem, but you might find it useful to convert all the dates to NSDate objects (so that you can be certain that the problem is NOT that the strings are actually not equal), and then check whether the day is the current day, or not, by using this category method on NSDate:

NSDate+Extensions.m:

```
static NSCalendar* ___calendar;

@implementation NSDate (Extensions)

    - (BOOL)isSameDay:(NSDate*)date
{
    NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents* comp1 = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date];
    NSDateComponents* comp2 = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:self];

    return [comp1 day]   == [comp2 day] &&
    [comp1 month] == [comp2 month] &&
    [comp1 year]  == [comp2 year];
}

-(NSCalendar*)currentCalendar
{
    if(___calendar == nil)
    {
        ___calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    }

    return ___calendar;
}

@end
```

NSDate+Extensions.h

```
@interface NSDate (Extensions)

- (BOOL)isSameDay:(NSDate*)date;

@end
```

Comment: Im not even sure If I have to do this process, because i already declared the event date as NSString and I already checked if the above code (my code) return the current date, and the date displayed it exactly matches the date format on the json file so I don't think it is a matching problem, the problem here is that the app loads all the events even though by default (the UIButton for today's event should only show today's event and when the UIButton for future events is pressed, all the future events should be loaded) but that is not happening and honestly Im not sure what should I do ..

Comment: Do u think I have to use two UITables ??

Comment: PS, for more information about my json file and my code plzz check my previous questions.

Comment: OK - if the date checking is definitely not the problem, then maybe a slightly different approach. Two things:
Firstly, when you first load your data, you could separate it into two arrays already - the first being today's data and the second being the data for all future days. Then have an enum somewhere with options TableViewDatesToday, TableViewDatesFuture, and in your table view's data source methods, have a switch or if statement so that if you are using the TableViewDatesToday you use the TodayArray as the data source and if using TableViewDatesFuture use the FutureDates array.

Comment: The second could be to call upcomingEvents manually after the data has loaded, and then to store this return value to dateEvents and make sure that the dateEvents array, and NOT the events array is used as the table view data source. You would need a second method called todayEvents or similar for when the user changes to today's events, and store this value to dateEvents before reloading the table view.